# Can I zip a file using strong passphrase (AES 256 Encryption) using Mule 4?

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb

I have a requirement for zipping an xml file using Strong passphrase  with AES 256 Encryption so that outside world can not be able to decrypt that file.

I have seen some java api component is there to achive this .

But my Question is using Mule 4 is there any way to achieve this?

I am unable to find any mule 4 component does this same thing.
Input will be -- xml file
output will be -- zip file ( with password protected, AES 256 Encryption)

Answer (score 0):

MuleSoft provides a [Compression Module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/compression-module/2.2/#common-use-cases-for-the-connector) that can create zip files but it doesn't seem to support encrypting files.

A solution is to implement it in Java code using some library. I recommend to create a Mule Module for easier reusing in Mule applications.